# Multiple Accounts on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I've a rails project which I want to deploy on Heroku. I am using the link  `https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts` for managing multiple accounts on heroku. But whenever i am running the command `heroku accounts:set personal` It is showing an error like that

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777  
 !    Heroku client internal error.  
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com  
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new  

    Error:       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)  
    Backtrace:   /Users/sumitkalra1984/.heroku/plugins/heroku-  accounts/lib/accounts/heroku/command/accounts.rb:111:in `set'  
                 /Users/sumitkalra1984/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:213:in `run'
                 /Users/sumitkalra1984/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 /usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku accounts:set personal  
    Plugins:     heroku-accounts  
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.0.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet the you found a solution to your problem, but just in case (and for other like me) you just have to init a git repo. If you try this command in a directory without git repo you will get this error.

Cheers !